# How can I build a Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core .exe file on a developer machine?

Tags: exe, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

Please see *Solution* section below for the TLDR.

I used the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and upgraded to Visual Studio 2017. I am developing a .NET Core console application. **I am talking here only about my local development machine, which has Visual Studio installed and it has .NET Core runtimes and SDKs installed.**

In Visual Studio 2015, project.json files were used, and by default the build process produced a DLL file in the `bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1`, that one could run using the `dotnet run` command. But there was an option to make a minor tweak in the project.json file:

```
...
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
...
```

->

```
...
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1"
},
...
```

And adding a `runtimes` section, such as

```
"runtimes": {
  "win10-x64": {}
}
```

And if you did this and built your project, an EXE file was created that **you could run directly, without using `dotnet run`**.

Now the question is, is the same possible in Visual Studio 2017 using .csproj XML files? And more specifically, **is it possible without the heavy self-contained deployments**? I do want it without the full SDD publish because I use these executables for just local testing during the development. Once the project is to be released, I do the SDD publish, but that is very inconvenient during the development process.

The project was converted to Visual Studio 2017, but it only generates DLL files again. So, I tried to create a completely new and empty *Hello, World!* program and try to get EXE file from it. The *Hello, World!* csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This only generates a DLL file that you can run with `dotnet run`. It is possible to make a change to this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net46</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

which is very close to what I want - generating an EXE file. However, this creates EXE file that runs .NET Framework 4.6, not .NET Core. So, it does not solve the problem. **What I really want is .NET Core executable without having to do self-contained deployment. Is it possible?**

#### Solution

I just found out that this is indeed possible. I just don't know how to do it in the IDE. What currently happens if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> in the IDE produces the same result as the command:

```
dotnet build --configuration Debug
```

And what I want can be produced by command:

```
dotnet build --configuration Debug --runtime win10-x64
```

So what I really want now is modify the default IDE build command to replicate this behavior with `--runtime win10-x64` parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET Core, if you want an `.exe` produced during `dotnet build`, you need to supply the runtime that you want the executable built for.

In project.json, you did it as you describe above by removing `type: platform` and adding a `runtimes` section.

In .csproj, you do it by specifying the MSBuild property named `RuntimeIdentifier`. On the command-line, when you say `dotnet build --runtime win10-x64`, the `--runtime` value gets passed into MSBuild has the `RuntimeIdentifier` property.

One option is you can purely set the `RuntimeIdentifier` in your .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now when you build in Visual Studio, it will produce an `.exe` in the build output folder.

#### Alternatively

I'm not sure if you are interested in this or not, but it sounds like you just want a way to run your application without calling `dotnet run`. If this is true, you don't need to set a runtime at all. By default your application gets built into `bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\AppName.dll`. You can run your application by saying `dotnet bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\AppName.dll`, which is basically what `dotnet run` does under the covers.

Comment: Works! Tx a lot. I would just add that one should mind the singular of `RuntimeIdentifier` as there also seems to be a semicolon separated list called `RuntimeIdentifiers` which apparently does something else.

Comment: `RuntimeIdentifiers` is the list of available runtimes that your project can target. Just like `TargetFrameworks` is the list of available frameworks that your project can target. A difference is when you build, it builds for all target frameworks, but it only builds them for the "runtime agnostic" or "portable" runtime.  To build/publish for a specific runtime, you have to specify one using the `RuntimeIdentifier` MSBuild property (or `--runtime` on the dotnet command line).